# xbindkeys bind cursor move to right or left key press

Tags: linux, debian, xbindkeys

I would like to program my mouse such that whenever the cursor is shifted right or left, the OS interprets this as a right key press or left key press.
Which mouse events correspond to cursor right and left, and what would be the syntax to use in xbindkeys (as this seems like the right tool for it).

Using `xev -event mouse` I see the cursor move gives MotionNotify events - can somehow cause the reception of this event to cause a right/left key press?

Comment: Would a python script that achieves the goal be good?

Comment: If compatible with Python 2.7.9, sure. I was working on a C solution using xlib functions but still stuck on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This python script using the [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package achieves the desired goal.

```
import time
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

prevX = -1
def on_move(x, y):
  global prevX
  if prevX == -1:
    prevX = x
  elif prevX < x:
    keyboard.press(Key.right)
    keyboard.release(Key.right)
  elif prevX > x:
    keyboard.press(Key.left)
    keyboard.release(Key.left)
  if prevX != x:
    prevX = x

listener = mouse.Listener(
  on_move=on_move)
listener.daemon = True
listener.start()

while True:
  time.sleep(1)
```

Adjusted to trigger a key press only after a determined number of mouse events on a direction:

```
import time
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

sensitivity = 20 # number of events to trigger key press
prevX = -1
leftEvents = 0
rightEvents = 0
def on_move(x, y):
  global prevX
  global leftEvents
  global rightEvents

  if prevX == -1:
    prevX = x
  elif prevX < x:
    rightEvents += 1
    leftEvents = 0
  elif prevX > x:
    leftEvents += 1
    rightEvents = 0
  if rightEvents == sensitivity:
    keyboard.press(Key.right)
    keyboard.release(Key.right)
    rightEvents = 0
  if leftEvents == sensitivity:
    keyboard.press(Key.left)
    keyboard.release(Key.left)
    leftEvents = 0
  if prevX != x:
    prevX = x

listener = mouse.Listener(
  on_move=on_move)
listener.daemon = True
listener.start()

while True:
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you! While it does work, the precision is a bit too fine-grained at the moment, making the right-key and left-key events go crazy :) . Ideally it would only respond to very clear swipes right or left, i.e. if we have 10 move right events in a row or something.

Comment: You're welcome!
I edited the answer with this in mind. Adjust `sensitivity` to your desired value :)